# Why I have to pre-set the collection and document name in GeoFireStore to setlocation

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I want to `setLocation` automatically from my app without presetting **collection** and **document** name.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CollectionReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("collection");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        geoFire.setLocation("firebase-hq", new GeoLocation(26.48956, 94.89945));
```

Comment: To start the search, do you get any error message when you do not pre-set the collection and document name?

Comment: No I don't get any error when I just setLocation```geoFire.setLocation("firebase-hq", new GeoLocation(26.48956, 94.89945));``` it just do nothing.

Comment: I do get error when I add `onCompleteListener`

Comment: From https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android/blob/master/README.md I see that A GeoFirestore object is used to read and write geo location data to your Firestore database and to create queries. To create a new GeoFirestore instance you need to attach it to a Firestore collection reference. Please look at the link to find more description.

Comment: Thanks.. But **imperiumlabs** is in Kotlin and I am working with java. I am using this https://github.com/suiko1984/geofirestore-android

Comment: I will continue to look but there is a team answering these kinds of questions like yours here: https://github.com/suiko1984/geofirestore-android/issues

Comment: Thanks MeTech.. is there any way that I can chat with you in case I need help from you.

Comment: You may open a new thread if you have further concerns.